# I want to do some experiment on SQL Server cluster to gain some experience on it, where should I start?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, cluster-computing

I want to do some experiment on **SQL Server cluster** to gain some experience on it, where should I start? I just have some basic concept of cluster and don't have any experience. Anyone can tell me some material that I can reference to? Great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here: [Getting Started with SQL Server 2008 R2 Failover Clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx). Make sure you look at the links at the bottom of this page

SQL Server 2008 Failover Clustering http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/D/69D1FEA7-5B42-437A-B3BA-A4AD13E34EF6/SQLServer2008FailoverCluster.docx